# Rounding to user-defined number in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with rounding to user defined numbers.

I have a MxN matrix with different numbers between -3 and 12.

And then I have to round each number in the matrix to the nearst of `[-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]` I have red some about the rounding and floor function, but can't figure out how to round towards a specific number.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`interp1`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with the `'nearest'` option:

```
x = [-2.1, 1.5; 5.7, 10.8]; % data values
y = [-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12]; % allowed values
result = interp1(y,y,x,'nearest');
```

This gives

```
result =
    -3     2
     7    10
```

---

If you prefer to do it manually: compute all pairwise absolute differences, find the minimizing index for each data value, and index into the matrix of allowed values:

```
[~, ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, x(:).',y(:))), [], 1);
result = reshape(y(ind), size(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is the [`discretize` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html):

```
>> % The set of values
>> setValues = [-3 0 2 4 7 10 12]';
>> % Find the midpoints between values to set as bin edges
>> binEdges = 0.5*(setValues(1:(end-1)) + setValues(2:end));
>> % Test a whole range of values
>> A = (-3.5:0.5:12.5)';
>> % Use discretize and include edges at -Inf and Inf to
>> % make sure we have the right # of bins
>> D = setValues(discretize(A, [-Inf; binEdges; Inf]));
>> % Compare the original values with the discretized version.
>> [A D]
```